# PHP/MYSQL advanced search script. How?

Tags: php, mysql

I need some guidance to make an advanced search script for a website I'm working on.

I already know how to search the database for simple queries. The problem I'm encountering right now is how to search, when using multiple select boxes. For example:

[image]

This is just a simple form with different search options. The question is:

The visitor can choose to search on a country or city, both or even with all three options.

How do I catch that in the PHP script? Do I have to check if for example a city has been chosen, and fire a query based on that? But if I do that I would have to make different queries based on each select option.

In pseudo-code it would be something like this: (I imagine)

if country and city and something else is not null, launch a query to search in all three tables in the database.

**But what to do when just the country has been chosen? Or just the city?**

Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you have already answered your own question.

Comment: Well, the simple way to accomplish this is to plug in something like [Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.overview.html) or [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/), but that may depend on your definition of the work "simple" :)

Comment: In your "pseudo code" you mention that city and country are in separate tables. Is that true? Or are they separate columns within the same table? If they are in fact in a separate table you'll need to join the tables so you can get a unified result set.

Comment: @sholsinger: that was just some example code. I don't have any country/city tables in my database. Thanks for your answer!

@Matt: Thanks mate!

@Andy: No I didn't. The other answers below answer my question. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like using an array to join conditions so I don't have to worry about leading or trailing AND's.

```
$conditions = array();
if ($formCondition1) {
  $conditions[] = 'state = "'.$somevalue.'"';
}
if ($formCondition2) {
  $conditions[] = 'country = "'.$somevalue.'"';
}
...
if ($formConditionN) {
  $conditions[] = 'N = "'.$somevalue.'"';
}
```

//finally join the conditions together, the simplest case is with ANDs (if you need to add ORs, which it sounds like you don't, then this code would be a bit more complex)

```
$sqlStatement = 'SELECT field1, field2 FROM tableABC WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $conditions);
```

EDIT: don't forget to escape the input to prevent injection attacks, and of course test to make sure there are at least 1 condition before running the query.
EDIT: lol jswolf and I think very much alike :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I think I'll go with this answer, even if the two others are working also great.

Thanks a lot all of you for your help!

Answer (score 5):

I make a `$where` array, add my conditions to it as necessary, and then `implode` it with ' AND ' as the glue. So something like:

```
$where = array();
if $city is defined
    $where[] = "city = '".mysql_real_escape_string($city)."'";
fi
if $country is defined
    $where[] = "country = '".mysql_real_escape_string($country)."'";
fi
...

if(count($where)) {
    $query.= ' WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $where);
}
```

Comment: That's very simple and elegant looking. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I would try something like:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ";
if ($country != '') {
    $qry .= "country='".mysql_real_escape_string($country)."' AND "
}
if ($city != '') {
    $qry .= "city='".mysql_real_escape_string($city)."' AND "
}
$qry .= '1';
$res = mysql_query($qry);
```

The query is built up depending on what is set. Note the "1" on the end of the query string which is always true. This is needed to follow the "WHERE" if $country and $city are both empty, or to follow the last "AND" if they are not.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have now 3 different answers, they all work and I don't know which one to use. Thanks again.

Comment: I think this is one of the perfect answer for advanced search concept. thanks for sharing this:)...